# Test - How to check if something was added to the HashMap

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that simply just add something to the hashmap. My test for it looks like this:

```
    Collection<SomeCollection> colelction = setUpConfluenceUsers();
    String group = "a";
    String group2 = "s";
    Parser collection = new ParserImpl();

    //when
    parser.map(group,users);
```

hashmap is initialised on top off the class. I want to test if this works. I just simply do not know how to check if that list contains expected elements. It would be simple to check if that method would return something.

For now my parser looks like this:

```
public static final String SEARCH_REGEX = "([\\s>])@(\\w+(?:[-\\.]\\w+)*)";

public static final int GROUP = 2;
private List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();

Map hashMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<SomeCollection>>();


@Nonnull
@Override
public List<String> find(String body) {

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(SEARCH_REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = r.matcher(body);

    MatchResultsIterable resultIterable = new MatchResultsIterable(matcher);

    for (MatchResult matchResult : resultIterable) {
        list.add(matchResult.group(GROUP));
    }

    return list;
}

@Nonnull
@Override
public String parse(String body) {

    return body;
}

@Override
public void map(@Nonnull String group, @Nonnull Collection<SomeCollection> users) {
    hashMap.put(group, users);
}
```

I would like to make some sort of assertion to check if map cworks correctly. Any ideas, code snippets would be nice.

Comment: Is `parser` a Mockito Object? If so, `parser.map(group,users);` will do nothing.

Comment: Retrieve the hashmap and verify(hashmap).put(group, users).

Comment: @Manu can I somehow assert that it contains my elements ?

Comment: Your code is a bit incomplete.. What do you do with the hashMap in your class besides putting information in it? Do you ever return it, as in, does it have a getter? Is it really default visibility?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what your parser class is, but one solution is to create a test-only constructor for this class and pass a spy or mock of your map to it; for instance:

```
@Test
public void mapIsFilled()
{
    final Map<Foo, Bar> map = mock(Map.class);
    final Parser parser = new Parser(map);

    parser.whatever();

    very(map).put(...);
}
```

A more precise answer requires that you post the code of your parser class.

Comment: It is just simple class with three methods that do not depend on each other.

Comment: Then you can just dump its code in the question, right?

Comment: Code is now in the question